# Second monitor suddenly upside down and shows bios logo and the cursor is X

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, cursor

I have just booted my computer up, and one of my monitors is suddenly upside down and only shows my bios logo. I can move my mouse to it, but it appears as an X. Also, for some reason after entering my password, my bios logo also flashes onto the screen before loading to the desktop.

I did look in nvidia-settings, and found that somehow the display had been set to 'invert', so I changed that.

I was using my computer earlier today, just using YouTube and had not made any changes to anything.

Does anyone have ideas what went wrong, and what I can do to fix it?

I have tried switching from nvidia's drivers to the open-source driver, but then the monitor would be black on the login screen (though it was receiving a signal).

I have tried using both of my monitors by themselves, and both work fine alone.

Thanks

Comment: It is odd that the logo for the computer manufacturer is being displayed as a background with the older X-Windows cursor appearing. This is not something I've seen on any version of Ubuntu, though. Which version of Ubuntu Desktop are you running? Are you running a different desktop environment or window manager?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu LTS 20.04 running pretty much out of the box. I just tried to reinstall my nvidia drivers (not sure I did it right), and now the second monitor has a white line in the top left and still shows the cursor X but no mobo logo.

Comment: I did just get a "Ubunutu ran into a problem" Xorg crashed, and it mentioned nvidia a bunch so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: "somehow the display had been set to invert ... and had not made any changes to anything" - any chance someone has access to your PC and is messing with you? If it's at work, the suspect might be the person in the next cubicle over.

Comment: Nope, no one else has used this computer. I live just with my wife and we have been watching TV together between me using my computer earlier and now.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the `xserver-xorg` package and the problem seems to be fixed. You can also reinstall it by running:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```